# Can't communicate with MySQL from django, but can directly in python

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache, python-2.7

I'm setting up a django web site locally on Windows with Apache, django 1.6 and MySQL 5.5.8. I've created a test database and populated it with a couple of sample records in the MyPHPAdmin interface. It has a user specifically for django, with full permissions (for that database only).

In a python session I can interact with the database using this function

```
def TestConnection():
    import MySQLdb
    db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="django", passwd="nu_django", db="nutana_django")
    cursor=db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from test")

    for x in range(0,cursor.rowcount):
        row=cursor.fetchone()
        print row[0], ' --> ', row[1]
```

and it outputs the records of the db, so I seem to have MySQL, MySQLdb and python working together properly.

Next, in django, I've created an app called Courses using "python manage.py startapp Courses", and edited my settings.py file to include Courses in the Installed_Apps and defined the database connection like this:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'Nutana.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Nutana.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'nutana_django',
        'USER':'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'nu_django',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':   '80'
    }
}
```

Last step is Apache. I've added the WSGI module to apache and appended the following to the end of the file:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias /Nutana F:/Web_Django/Nutana/Nutana/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath F:/Web_Django/Nutana
<Directory F:/Web_Django/Nutana/Nutana/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

where the paths above are all correct, but I'm not convinced are all necessary.

Within f:\web_django\Nutana\Courses I've edited models.py to the following:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Course(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField('Start Date')
    Quota = models.IntegerField()

class Course_Venue(models.Model):
    Course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Max_Size = models.IntegerField()
```

Ok... now when I run "python manage.py sql Courses" from the command prompt in "f:\web_django\Nutana", where manage.py lives, I get an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 0")
```

That's a lot of configuration, and I don't know where I've gone wrong! I don't think Apache is the issue here, but I've included it to be thorough. If I call up a non existent web page the 404 error includes reference to wsgi, so maybe thats all good?

```
localhost
16/12/2013 10:14:34 AM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.6 PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Comment: The port for mysql is 3306, not 80. If it is the default port you are using, just leave it blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL server has port 3306 instead of 80!

Comment: You can probably leave out the port setting and it will use the default port.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I won't embarrass myself further by telling you how long I've been poking at this! Where would the MySQL port be defined? I can't find anything in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: If you use linux `cat /etc/services | grep mysql`

Comment: If you haven't manually configured it, it's probably running on the default port.